# which rest api can be used to get the message sent from other twitter account to my twitter account

Tags: twitter

Assume I have one twitter account called "A", any other people who have twitter account can send message to me without following me. How to get these messages using Twitter REST API?
Which document describes this API?

Answer (score 0):

I find the API should be direct_messages
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/direct_messages

Using [twitcurl C++ libary](https://code.google.com/p/twitcurl/), I can get the direct_messages from other twitter user